# How to fill dynamic form fields using capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, capybara, poltergeist

I have a form that contains a select box and a text field.

The text field is displayed dynamically based on the selectbox selection. If the value of selectbox is "Yes", then the text field will be displayed and vice versa.
 I am running an rspec test and filled the select box value with "Yes"

```
select 'Yes', from: 'property[have_water_bills]'
```

Now i want to fill a value on the text field

```
fill_in 'property[irrigation_cycle_count]', with: 5
```

But i am getting the following error.

```
Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find field "property[irrigation_cycle_count]"
```

That is, capybara cannot find the dynamic element. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: What event is being used to trigger the display of the next field (change, blur, etc)?.  Also, are you sure this test is being run with Poltergeist?

Comment: click event is used to trigger the next field. Yes, the test is run with Poltergeist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got this to work using the following piece of code

```
page.execute_script("$('#have_water_bills').val('true').trigger('click')")
```

Comment: So you're okay with your app being unusable by keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

Poltergeist doesn't gemerate a `click` event when choosing an item from a select.  It  generates a `focus` on the option, `change` on the select, `blur` on the option.  It is more like if a user selected the option with keyboard instead of using a mouse.  You probably should be doing the logic to display your text field on the `change` event anyway so that it works if people use a mouse or a keyboard to navigate around your page.  It also makes more sense to run your show/hide logic on the `change` event because that's what you actually care about, not clicks.